# Reaction of hydrogen peroxide with acetic acid and potassium permanganate

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, redox, aqueous-solution

I conducted an experiment where I mixed hydrogen peroxide $\ce{H2O2}$, acetic acid $\ce{CH3COOH}$ and potassium permanganate $\ce{KMnO4}$ under vigorous stirring. The reaction hasn't stopped after 15 min and the colour is cycling between pink and colourless whenever I add more potassium permanganate.

What reaction is going on? I think despite a medium created with weak acid, acidified potassium permanganate is a much stronger oxidising agent and it should react with a lot of peroxide rather than the opposite.

But hydrogen peroxide and acetic acid react to form [peracetic acid $\ce{CH3CO3H}$ (PAA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peracetic_acid). I don’t know if PAA reacts with potassium permanganate or something entirely different occurs.

I am concerned about the reaction and products. The mix smells strongly of acetic acid and most of the permanganate is still in there. Could it be the manganese oxide formed in the reaction being oxidised? Well first of all no bubbles the limiting reagent of the reaction was hydrogen peroxide and I used aqueous potassium permanganate. And by most of the permanganate was still there I meant I added half a teaspoon of permanganate and I used less than 1% acetic acid and 6.5 percent peroxide. I was trying an acid catalysed reaction between and oxidiser permanganate and and reductant peroxide. When I drained the solution (by excess of water)a most of the amount added of permanganate was in the solution with manganese oxide indication it reacted with the peroxide.

Comment: Try to better explain what you have done. In which order have you mixed the three components ? And how much of each ? How many times ? Did you use solid permanganate or its solution ? In this case which concentration ? The same question for hydrogen peroxide : have you used $30$% or $3$% hydrogen peroxide ? Did you use pure acetic acid, or an aqueous solution ? Which concentration ? What is the meaning of "most of the permanganate was still in there" ? Please explain thoroughly all what you have done 
!

Comment: Please be careful, peroxide and permanganate are strong oxidizers.  Acetic acid is potential fuel.  But what you may be doing is *oxidizing* the peroxide (with permanganate).  Did you see bubbles?

Comment: The limiting reagent was not defined. Acetic acid is a suitable solvent for permanganate or chromate oxidations at low temperatures but still should be used very carefully. This idea of mixing peroxides with a strong oxidzer and a possible reductant sounds like potential bomb making. This person is playing with chemicals not "conducting an experiment"

Comment: [The Kinetics of the Acid-Catalyzed Formation of Peracetic Acid from Acetic Acid and Hydrogen Peroxide](https://doi.org/10.1246/bcsj.38.2103) has been studied in details as early as 1965.

Comment: Well first of all no bubbles the limiting reagent of the reaction was hydrogen peroxide and I used aqueous potassium permanganate. And by most of the permanganate was still there I meant I added half a teaspoon of permanganate and I used less than 1% acetic acid and 6.5 percent peroxide. I was trying an acid catalysed reaction between and oxidiser permanganate and and reductant peroxide. When I drained the solution (by excess of water)a most of the  amount added of permanganate was in the solution with manganese oxide indication it reacted with the peroxide.